# Conditional Entropy Formula for a Masking Network

Tags: entropy, information-theory

I want to prove the following, for a given image distribution $P(X), \mathcal{X} \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times m}$, we have a masking model, $\phi:X \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{n\times m}$. We also have the complement mask $\bar{\phi}$, which basically does the complement masking of $\phi$. I want to find the entropy $H(X \circ \phi(X) | X \circ \bar{\phi}(X))$, $\circ$ is Hadamard product. Here is my attempt:

$$\begin{align}
H(X \circ \phi(X) | X \circ \bar{\phi}(X)) &= \sum_{x_1\in\mathcal{X}}P(x_1)H(X \circ \phi(X) | x_1 \circ \bar{\phi}(x_1)) \\
&= -\sum_{x_1\in\mathcal{X}, x_2 \in\mathcal{X}}P(x_1)P(x_2 \circ \phi(x_2) | x_1 \circ \bar{\phi}(x_1))\dots\\
\dots\log P(x_2 \circ \phi(x_2) | x_1 \circ \bar{\phi}(x_1))
\end{align}$$

Based on this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.07287.pdf), page 12, equation 11, this quantity should equal to:

$\mathbb{E}[\log P(X \circ \phi(X) | X \circ \bar{\phi}(X)]$

But I am not sure how to further progress to get their equation.